# Need to create @namest and @nameend attributes in the 'entry' element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

if we get `<gridSpan val="4"/>` create the `@namest` and `@nameend` attributes in the '`entry`' element.

**NOTE:**  `May be gridSpan element will appear in 3rd entry then @namest and @nameend will be come in the third entry`

```
then output should be <entry namest="c1" nameend="c4">

<gridSpan val="3"/>

then output should be <entry namest="c2" nameend="c3">

<gridSpan val="2"/>

then output should be <entry namest="c1" nameend="c2">
```

**Xml:**

```
<tbl>
<tblPr>
<tblW w="9885" type="dxa"/>
</tblPr>
<tblGrid>
<gridCol w="1488"/>
<gridCol w="3100"/>
<gridCol w="3267"/>
<gridCol w="2021"/>
</tblGrid>
<tr>
<tc><p>Content here</p></tc>
<tc><p>content here</p></tc>
<tc>content here</tc>
<tc>contenet</tc>
</tr>
<tr>
<tc>
<tcPr>
<!-- May be gridSpan element will appear in 3rd entry then @namest and named will be come in the third entry
<gridSpan val="4"/>
</tcPr>
<p>Content here</p>
</tc>
</tr>
</tbl>
```

**Output:**

```
<table>
<tgroup cols="4">
<colspec colname="c1" colnum="1"/>
<colspec colname="c2" colnum="2"/>
<colspec colname="c3" colnum="3"/>
<colspec colname="c4" colnum="4"/>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<table>
<tgroup cols="4">
<colspec colname="c1" colnum="1"/>
<colspec colname="c2" colnum="2"/>
<colspec colname="c3" colnum="3"/>
<colspec colname="c4" colnum="4"/>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
<row namest="c1" nameend="c4">
<entry>Content here</entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template that transforms ***tc*** elements into ***entry*** to get the *namest* value you can count preceding-sibling cells and add 1.

```
<xsl:attribute name="namest" select="count(preceding-sibling::tc) + 1"/>
```

To get the *nameend* value you need to add span value to your current position

```
<xsl:attribute name="nameend" select="count(preceding-sibling::tc) + tcPr/gridSpan/@val"/>
```

So template that matches ***tc*** can be following:

```
<xsl:template match="tc">
    <entry>
        <xsl:if test="tcPr/gridSpan/@val">
            <xsl:variable name="spanValue" select="tcPr/gridSpan/@val"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="namest" select="count(preceding-sibling::tc) + 1"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="nameend" select="count(preceding-sibling::tc) + $spanValue"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

Please note that your template can be different and contain namespaces.

So output with table provided in example will look like this:

```
<table>
<tgroup cols="4">
    <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2"/>
    <colspec colname="c3" colnum="3"/>
    <colspec colname="c4" colnum="4"/>
    <tbody>
        <row>
            <entry>
                Content here
            </entry>
            <entry>
                content here
            </entry>
            <entry>content here</entry>
            <entry>contenet</entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry namest="1" nameend="4">
                Content here
            </entry>
        </row>
    </tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

***namest*** and ***nameend*** can be added to any cell so if your table will look like this:

```
<tbl>
<tblPr>
    <tblW w="9885" type="dxa"/>
</tblPr>
<tblGrid>
    <gridCol w="1488"/>
    <gridCol w="3100"/>
    <gridCol w="3267"/>
    <gridCol w="2021"/>
</tblGrid>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>The first cell</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>The second cell</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>The third cell</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>The fourth cell</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <gridSpan val="4"/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>The first cell with gridSpan @val=4</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <gridSpan val="3"/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>The first cell with gridSpan @val=3</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>The fourth cell</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tc>
        <p>The first cell</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <p>The second cell</p>
    </tc>
    <tc>
        <tcPr>
            <gridSpan val="2"/>
        </tcPr>
        <p>The first cell with gridSpan @val=2</p>
    </tc>
</tr>
</tbl>
```

You will get this in the output:

```
<table>
<tgroup cols="4">
    <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2"/>
    <colspec colname="c3" colnum="3"/>
    <colspec colname="c4" colnum="4"/>
    <tbody>
        <row>
            <entry>
                The first cell
            </entry>
            <entry>
                The second cell
            </entry>
            <entry>
                The third cell
            </entry>
            <entry>
                The fourth cell
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry namest="1" nameend="4">
                The first cell with gridSpan @val=4
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry namest="1" nameend="3">
                The first cell with gridSpan @val=3
            </entry>
            <entry>
                The fourth cell
            </entry>
        </row>
        <row>
            <entry>
                The first cell
            </entry>
            <entry>
                The second cell
            </entry>
            <entry namest="3" nameend="4">
                The third cell with gridSpan @val=2
            </entry>
        </row>
    </tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

**Update:**

For more complex cases, when preceding tc elements contain gridSpan you will need to count also gridSpan of preceding elements. So template can look like so:

```
    <xsl:template match="tc">
    <entry>
        <xsl:if test="tcPr/gridSpan/@val">
            <xsl:variable name="spanValue" select="tcPr/gridSpan/@val"/>
            <xsl:variable name="precedingTcNumber"
                          select="sum(for $tcElem in preceding-sibling::tc return(if($tcElem/tcPr/gridSpan/@val) then($tcElem/tcPr/gridSpan/@val) else(1)))"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="namest" select="$precedingTcNumber + 1"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="nameend" select="$precedingTcNumber + $spanValue"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```